# How to retrain Inception image classifier in Hadoop environment

Tags: python, hadoop, tensorflow, pyspark, hadoop-streaming

Recently I tried Google's Inception image classifier on my PC with Win10 operating system. Basically I went through on this [tutorial/manual](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#0).

In a nutshell the steps were these:

1. Install Docker
2. Install Tensorflow
3. Get the pictures
4. Retrieve the training code (retrain.py)
5. Retrain Inception (run retrain.py)
6. Use the classifier on your images

My problem is I want to do the same but in a Hadoop environment and unfortunately I have no idea how to do that because I new in Hadoop. I tried to google this topic but I didn't find any helpful result.

My Hadoop cluster contains 4 Raspberry Pi with Hadoop, Hive and Spark. If I'm right there are at least two way to do the retraining process on Hadoop:

1. Create a Hadoop streaming to run the phyton code
2. Install pySpark and do the "magic" using that

---

Going with the first choice I imagine that the steps may be these:

(Python is pre-installed on NOOB)

1. Put the images into the hdfs
2. Install the Tensorflow library and tools
3. Retrieve the training code and the full sample set of Tensorflow
4. Create a Hadoop Streaming to run the retraining process

   ```
   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
   -input myInputDirs \
   -output myOutputDir \
   -mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper \
   -reducer /bin/wc
   -file (a python file which executes **)
   ```
5. Use the classifier on your images

   ```
   ** = $python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
   --bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
   --how_many_training_steps 500 \
   --model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
   --output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
   --output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
   --image_dir /tf_files/(myImages)
   ```

---

Going with the second way... I have no idea

---

If somebody could give some advice, detailed steps or just show me some direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure your environment for HDFS. You can also run your program in docker with docker file: https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile.hdfs . You may need to copy your training program into the image.

Then, after you copy the data to HDFS, you can just specify `"hdfs://namenode/file/path"` as your model input. TensorFlow's gfile module can recognize the HDFS URI.